# Need help loading multiple CSS files on click using Jquery

Tags: jquery

Using the following bit of code I am able to successfully load a single CSS file into my head section using ajax.

The trouble for me begins when attempting to load two or more css files via the following two variations of code.

```
  $("#getCustomCSS a").click(function() {
   $.get('https://website.com/post-2709.css , 
     https://website.com/post-1506.css', function(data) {
          var style = document.createElement('style'),
          head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement;
    style.type = "text/css";
        style.textContent = style.text = data;

    head.appendChild(style, head.firstChild); 
    console.log( "Click GET CSS 2709 & 1506 Successful!" );
   });

$("#pageMenuHome").removeClass("On");
$(".hamburger").removeClass("is-active");
console.log( "Click GET CSS Successful!" );

$('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1500);

});
```

OR VARIATION TWO

```
  $("#getCustomCSS a").click(function() {
   $.get('https://website.com/post-2709.css', function(data) {
          var style = document.createElement('style'),
          head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement;
    style.type = "text/css";
        style.textContent = style.text = data;

    head.appendChild(style, head.firstChild); 
    console.log( "Click GET CSS 2709 Successful!" );
   });

$.get('https://website.com/post-1506.css', function(data) {
          var style = document.createElement('style'),
          head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement;
    style.type = "text/css";
        style.textContent = style.text = data;

    head.appendChild(style, head.firstChild); 
    console.log( "Click GET CSS 1506 Successful!" );
   });

$("#pageMenuHome").removeClass("On");
$(".hamburger").removeClass("is-active");
console.log( "Click GET CSS Successful!" );

$('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},1500);

});
```

Currently on click, console shows "Click GET CSS Successful!" but does not show "Click GET CSS 2709 Successful!" however the jquery works and the stylesheet is added to the head.

What I would like:

- To be able to add more than a single css file this way. When I add a second one - there are no console errors but the second css file doesn't load. I only get the first css file.

Comment: https://github.com/edjekadetje/css_changer

Comment: I am unable to structure the files in a manner needed for this option to work. BUT this is interesting and I'll keep it in mind for possible future projects of a different type. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me to download multiple CSS or JS files on element click:

(There is one caveat relating to AJAX. If you are using ajax calls this code will only retrieve and download files before an ajax call. After the call - the code doesn't execute. Thoughts on how to overcome this would be greatly appreciated.)

```
$('.getCSS a').one('click', function(e) {

function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)

} 

loadjscssfile("/post-1841.css", "css") 
loadjscssfile("/post-1886.css", "css")
loadjscssfile("/customcode.js", "js") 
loadjscssfile("/post-2299.css", "css") 
loadjscssfile("/post-2296.css", "css") 
loadjscssfile("/post-1680.css", "css") 
loadjscssfile("/post-1598.css", "css") 


    console.log( "ALL CSS & JS Downloaded" );


});
```